# In Rails, What should I render for JSON for a failed destroy request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I am the server and someone sends me a JSON request to destroy a model/record but the destroy request failed, what response should Igive them. I assume just send them back a no content will be bad because they will assume that the destroy is a success.

So my question is: What should I return? And why?

Also, is my code below following good convention? I don't know if it is okay to do a conditional statement in a destroy action, I also customised the error messages which seems to be not following convention:

```
def destroy
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.destroy
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: "Book was successfully deleted." }
    else
      format.html do
        error_messages = @book.errors.try(:messages)
        error_messages = error_messages[:base].join('. ') + '.' if error_messages.present?
        flash[:error] = "Book deletion failed. #{ error_messages }"
        redirect_to books_url
      end
    end
    format.json { head :no_content } # what should this be?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use `:unprocessable_entity` like this:

```
if @book.destroy
  # ...
  format.json { head :no_content }
else
  # ...
  format.json { head :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

---

I found this flow chart to be enlightening: [i.stack.imgur.com/whhD1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whhD1.png)

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful chart! Would you please give me a bit more explanation why returning unprocessable entity? For example, if a record cannot be deleted because still have associated record.

Comment: @HenryYang, I'm so sorry for late reply. You can read more at [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/41790-how-rails-chooses-error-pages-404-500-for-exceptions)

Comment: no worries, i read the link you sent me but I cannot see any explanation about choosing unprocessable_entity when trying to delete a record that still has associated record. However, I google 422 unprocessable entity and found some site (https://httpstatuses.com/422, https://www.keycdn.com/support/422-unprocessable-entity/) and I think it's suitable to use 422 in this context

Comment: because **The server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415 Unsupported Media Type status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 Bad Request status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.** suits this situation and that's the RFC for 422 unprocessable_entity

Comment: @HenryYang, Thank you so much. That were really great resources

Comment: thank you, your answer and resources are really helpful too!